# Enumeration value not returning with valueOf

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am confused at what is going on here.  It's a simple thing but for some reason I am getting the name of the enumeration and not the value.

Here is my class :

```
public class Class1{

  public enum SchoolEnum {
    01("MIDDLE_SCHOOL");

    private String value;

    SchoolEnum(String value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return String.valueOf(value);
    }
  }

  private SchoolEnum schoolEnum = null;

  public SchoolEnum getSchoolEnum () {
    return schoolEnum;
  }

  public void setSchoolEnum (SchoolEnum schoolEnum ) {
    this.schoolEnum= schoolEnum;
  }

}
```

Calling it in another class via this :

```
Class1 response = new Class1();
response.setSchoolEnum(Class1.SchoolEnum.valueOf("01"));
```

Whenever I try to get the value of the 01 Enum, I am simply getting 01 instead of the value MIDDLE_SCHOOL.  What is going on here ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. `SchoolEnum.valueOf` will return a `SchoolEnum`, not a String. If you want the String it points to, use `schoolEnum.value`. Where is it getting the enum when you want the String?

Comment: (I'm ignoring for a moment the fact that `01` is not a valid enum value name, so the code above won't actually compile...)

Comment: I'm not ignoring that. The posted code won't compile. `01` (zero one) is an illegal variable name. Enum constants don't have a value in the sense you mean, OP. The constant _is_ the value. You can define an attribute like you tried to do with your illegal constant and name it `value`, and that will be the "value" _attribute_ of the enum value. There's a section of the Java Tutorial on enums you should study, and the documentation on variable naming will help you, too.

Comment: And `String.valueOf(someString)` is unnecessarily redundant.

Comment: While I'm at it, `private SchoolEnum schoolEnum = null;` initializes `schoolEnum` to `null` twice, in case you care.

Answer (score 0):

I think your declaration is wrong.

```
01("MIDDLE_SCHOOL");
```

Above declaration will give you compile time error. As any variable name can't start with digit.

Some naming suggestions you can use.

```
_01("MIDDLE_SCHOOL");
ONE("MIDDLE_SCHOOL");
ZERO_ONE("MIDDLE_SCHOOL");
```